# Difference between C++ stream and print() - fillers

Tags: c++, fmt, c++23

It has been a while since I posted any questions on StackOverflow; I hope I remember more or less the appropriate way to address a question (sorry in advance).

I was playing with C++ streams and the FMT library, which provides a preview to C++23 print. Streams are chill when setting fillers to complete the display width of an integer. Example:

```
const int y = 730;
cout << "y = " << setw(5) << y << endl;
cout << "y = " << setfill('0') << setw(5) << y << endl;
cout << "y = " << setfill('X') << setw(5) << y << endl;
cout << "y = " << setfill('*') << setw(5) << y << endl;
```

The output is

```
y =   730
y = 00730
y = XX730
y = **730
```

I was trying to set the same fillers (including 'X' and '*' chars) using fmt::print—something like:

```
print("y = {:5d}\n", y);
print("y = {:05d}\n", y);
```

Well, I failed to include 'X' and '*'. I am not claiming it is a good idea to have random chars as fillers; I am just curious as I need to explain the difference between these commands to students.

Thanks in advance.
Vivian

Comment: Try adding the alignment specifier: https://godbolt.org/z/oaadTx5nY

Comment: The best thing you can do for such questions is to provide a piece of code we can run as is (with the right headers, with `main()`, etc). If there's also a godbolt link to quickly run it, that's a huge plus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The manual](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html#format-specification-mini-language) shows following grammar for integer format specifiers:

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign]["#"]["0"][width]["." precision]["L"][type]
fill        ::=  <a character other than '{' or '}'>
align       ::=  "<" | ">" | "^"
```

Here `format_spec` is the part inside of `{:` `}`.

So specifying a custom filler (`fill`) also requires specifying alignment (you want `>`, i.e. align to the right):

```
fmt::print("y = {:X>5d}\n", y); // XX730
fmt::print("y = {:*>5d}\n", y); // **730
```

Comment: Awesome - one quick change is that you need to remove the 0

Comment: @VivianMiranda Thanks, fixed. Interesting that it worked with `0` too.

Comment: it didn't worked with zero in my laptop (which is also interesting!)

Comment: @VivianMiranda Hmm, my guess is that you use an older version of libfmt.

Comment: @VivianMiranda The 0 (which *"enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types"*) in `{:X>05d}` is ignored by the trunk version, while up to 9.1 "dominates" over the fill char. I'm not sure what should be the expected behavior, here.

Comment: awesome - thank you so much for digging into this.

Comment: @Bob__ The C++ standard says that if *align* is present, the 0 will be squeezed out and not show up. http://eel.is/c++draft/format.string.std#8   Likely that {fmt} wants to follow that rule too.

Answer (score 5):

The alignment is mandatory when a filling character is given.

```
print("y = {:*>5}\n", y);
```